# multline environment with multiple equation numbers

Tags: amsmath, multline, tags

I would like `a` and `b` to have an equation number of their own, while maintaining the overall layout that `multline` offers. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multline}
    a \\
    b \\
    c
    \end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Comment: By default, all three lines have an equation number. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @Bernard I believe this is not true for `multline`. The manual says "Like `equation`, `multline` has only a single equation number".

Comment: what you probably want in a situation like this is `gather`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, "like" `gather`, "while maintaining the overall layout that `multline` offers".

Comment: Something like `\begin{gather}\shoveleft ... \shoveright\end{gather}`, if that worked.

Comment: the `\shoveleft` and `\shoveright` commands pfovided by `mathtools` only work with `multlined` (which is the "internal" equivalent of `multline'), so they're no help.  the only suggestion i can make offhand, then, is to add large `\hspace*`s to adjust the positioning of individual lines.  requesting extending the applicability of the `\shove...` commands seems not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @egreg's answer, this is what I came up with. It basically defines `\gatherleft` and `\gatherright` commands that are consistent in spacing with `\multline`, even with varying lengths of equation numbers (including tags).

It also works with different font sizes, so the `20pt` seem to be pretty constant. If anyone knows what those correspond to, I would be happy to modify my answer accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% Left-/right-aligned lines in gather, with spacing consistent with multline.
% Limitations: \tag{...}, if used, has to come BEFORE corresponding \gatherleft or \gatherright
\makeatletter
\newlength{\gatherlabelwidth}
\newcommand{\gatherbox}[2]{
    \settowidth{\gatherlabelwidth}{%
        \iftag@%
            \df@tag%
        \else%
            \stepcounter{equation}%
            \print@eqnum%
            \addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
        \fi%
    }
    \makebox[\displaywidth - \gatherlabelwidth - 20pt][#1]{$\displaystyle #2$}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\gatherleft}[1]{\gatherbox{l}{#1}}
\newcommand{\gatherright}[1]{\gatherbox{r}{#1}}

% for this MWE only:
\newcommand{\reset}{
    \setbox0=\vtop{\begin{multline}a\\b\\c\end{multline}}
    \setlength{\mytempheight}{\ht0}
    \addtolength{\mytempheight}{\dp0}
    \color{red}\vspace*{-\mytempheight}\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{color}
\newlength{\mytempheight}
\def\countervalue{0}
\newif\ifusetag

\begin{document}
    % Test some variations by uncommenting any line:
    % \tiny
    % \LARGE
    % \def\countervalue{6}
    % \def\countervalue{7}
    % \def\countervalue{8}
    % \def\countervalue{9}
    % \def\countervalue{96}
    % \def\countervalue{97}
    % \def\countervalue{98}
    % \def\countervalue{99}
    % \usetagtrue

    This is typeset with multline:
    \setcounter{equation}{\countervalue}\stepcounter{equation}\stepcounter{equation}
    \begin{multline}
        a\\b\\c
        \ifusetag
            \tag{my tag!}
        \else\fi
    \end{multline}

    \reset

    This is typeset with gather:
    \setcounter{equation}{\countervalue}
    \begin{gather}
        \gatherleft{a} \\
        b \\
        \ifusetag
            \tag{my tag!}
        \else\fi
        \gatherright{c}
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This maybe doesn't all the checks as in `multline`, but might be sufficient for your purposes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{nmultline}{%
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_nmultline_contents_seq { \\ } \BODY
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_nmultline_contents_seq \l_nmultline_first_tl
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_nmultline_contents_seq \l_nmultline_last_tl
  \begin{gather}
  \makebox[\dim_eval:n{\displaywidth-4em}][l]{$\displaystyle \l_nmultline_first_tl$} \\
  \seq_use:Nn \l_nmultline_contents_seq { \\ } 
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_nmultline_contents_seq { \\ }
  \makebox[\dim_eval:n{\displaywidth-4em}][r]{$\displaystyle \l_nmultline_last_tl$}
  \end{gather}
}
\seq_new:N \l_nmultline_contents_seq
\tl_new:N \l_nmultline_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l_nmultline_last_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
For comparison, first four rows
\begin{multline}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d
\end{multline}
and then two rows
\begin{multline}
a \\
b
\end{multline}
Now numbered:
\begin{nmultline}
a\label{a} \\
b\label{b} \\
c\label{c} \\
d\label{d}
\end{nmultline}
References: \eqref{a}, \eqref{c}, \eqref{bb}
\begin{nmultline}
a\label{aa} \\
b\label{bb}
\end{nmultline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I was looking for. Spacing is not perfectly identical, though - `nmultline` contents seems to be set a little farther away from both left and right page limits. Probably due to some space around the `\makebox`es, because I could not fix it by removing all white space from your MWE.

Comment: Or maybe `4em` used in `\displaywidth-4em` is just an imperfect approximation. `20pt` looks pretty good to me (or not, that messes with the equation numbers for the second line).